# Interface Builder for Dummies: how to set the action of my button to "selectNext"?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I am in "the Binding Inspector" of my button, but I don't know how to put the right information.

[image: IB]

- I guess I have to enter information only for "Target" (not for Argument
- I bind it to "Array Controller"

But then ? I have the choice between four subsections, and don't know which one to choose !

- Controller Key ???
- Model Key Path ???
- Value Transformer ???
- or : Selector Name ???

My guess would go with "Selector Name", but Xcode doesn't give any autocompletion...

(I want to call the method `selectNext`)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind from Button to ArrayController.

You can Drag from ArrayController to the button.

Or,

Select ArrayController -> connection's Inspector -> Recieved Actions -> Hook "selectNext:" to the button.

Comment: Thanks !!
Is it logical that I cannot do that ? What's the "Action Invocation" panel in the binding's inspector of a button ?

Comment: @Colas: It's for when you want to set the button's target and/or action dynamically at run time—e.g., have the button's target be whichever object is selected.